# How do I get the query quotas from Deployment Manager via the API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-deployment-manager

Over at https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/deploymentmanager.googleapis.com/quotas or https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?service=deploymentmanager.googleapis.com, I am able to see the query and well as the write quotas and are can determine if I'm going to hit limits if any.

Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to get these values programmatically using the Deployment Manager APIs (using Go) or using `gcloud`.

Am I missing something here, or there are some other ways of getting at these values, possibly, not via the APIs directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there's no way to get the quotas programmatically or with `gcloud`(apart from the [compute engine quotas](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#checking_your_quota)) , however, there's a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80238692) to get/set the project quotas via API. I suggest [starring](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue) this issue to track it and ask for updates from it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was wondering why only the compute related quotas are available, yet for the other APIs, one would have to use the site for details.

Answer (score 0):

knowing of no API, which could be used to do so ...

guess one could only limit the quota per user; see the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/reference/latest/parameters).

there are several questions concerning other API (all the same).